# How to pass a null value for a URL parameter to Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, url

Let's say I have a Java Spring MVC controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="showuser", method={RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView showUser(Model model, @RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams) throws Exception {
```

User has three fields (firstname, middlename, lastname) all of which are part of the unique ID for that record.

And middlename can be NULL.

I do this to view the user ...

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/viewuser?firstname=Bob&middlename=Tiberius&lastname=Jones
```

And when `middlename` is NULL, my code currently passes no value for middlename, like this ...

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/viewuser?firstname=Bob&middlename=&lastname=Jones
```

... but doesn't work because in the `requestParams` map, the value for `middlename` gets set to empty string, not NULL.

I need that value to be NULL, not empty string.

How do I pass NULL as the value for the `middlename` parameter?

I searched and found other answers that said to use `%00` or `%A0` for the value, but neither of these worked.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't send middlename from frontend

Comment: In my application, I verify on the backend that all required id fields were passed in (for other reasons), so I'll have to change some code on the backend, but I think this is the right answer.  So simple I didn't even think of it. ;-)